# The row is overwriting and not adding rows listview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Im sending the data from form1(Home) to form2 (StatusReport) but the information taken from form 1 is not adding to the next row in the form2, instead it is overwriting the same row. I did it on the form 1, the adding per row but from sending the data from form 1 to form 2, it's not adding properly.

Form 1 code

```
Dim recipientName As String = TextBox5.Text
Dim address As String = TextBox6.Text
Dim contactNumber As String = TextBox7.Text
Dim deliveryMode As String = ComboBox3.SelectedItem
Dim deliveryDate As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
```

Form 2 code

```
Dim recipientName As String = Home.TextBox5.Text
Dim address As String = Home.TextBox6.Text
Dim contactNumber As String = Home.TextBox7.Text
Dim deliveryMode As String = Home.ComboBox3.SelectedItem
Dim deliveryDate As Date = Home.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
Dim orderStatus As String = "Pending"

Dim str(6) As String
Dim lvItem As ListViewItem
str(0) = recipientName
str(1) = address
str(2) = contactNumber
str(3) = deliveryMode
str(4) = deliveryDate
str(5) = orderStatus
lvItem = New ListViewItem(str)
ListView1.Items.Add(lvItem)
```

Comment: Posted code posted should work.  Problem is somewhere else.  It's unclear what you mean by overwriting.  How is Form2 referencing Form1 (Home)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include. But im getting the information from textboxes in form1 then will be shown in listview in form2. Every time I click the button in form1 to send the information to listview, it will show in the first row. Then another input, the same row will just be over writed, the new input should be added in the next row, and it wont.

Comment: Are you expecting Form2 to show multiple rows?  It sounds like Form2 is being created every time, so the default is an empty ListView and you are only adding the one row every time.

Comment: Yes that's what Im expecting thank you. But how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, this is just the base. Just added some codes to fit into the required system.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim itm As New ListViewItem(TextBox1.Text)

        itm.SubItems.Add(TextBox2.Text)
        itm.SubItems.Add(TextBox3.Text)

        Form2.ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

        Form2.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Leaving this here as it can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new ListViewItem using a String Array creates a single ListViewItem with the array signifying the sub items.

Maybe simpler to create the ListViewItems individually and add them, like this:

```
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(recipientName))
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(Address))
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(contactNumber))
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(deliveryMode))
lv.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(recipientName))
```

etc.

You may want to clear the items first:

```
lv.Items.Clear()
```

Comment: Hi! thank you. I've tried this and it won't work for me, still the same problem with an added one, they just shows on first column,

Comment: Are you trying to add a single list item as a row containing multiple fields then? That's not what I understood from the question, sorry.

Comment: Yes. Then these datas came from textboxes from form1. It's finee, still thank you for contribution.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you are going back and forth between the 2 forms but this should get you started. Set up the columns in the `ListView` before adding any items. You can either do this once in code or at design time. `ListView`s hold `ListViewItems`. The first column is the `Text` property and the following columns are `SubItems`.

```
Private Sub CreateLVColumns()
    'you will probably want to do this at design time
    With ListView1.Columns
        .Add("Name")
        .Add("Address")
        .Add("Number")
        .Add("Mode")
        .Add("Date")
        .Add("Status")
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(Home.TextBox5.Text)
    With lvi.SubItems
        .Add(Home.TextBox6.Text)
        .Add(Home.TextBox7.Text)
        .Add(Home.ComboBox3.Text)
        .Add(Home.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString) 'you can add a format to the ToString
        .Add("Pending")
    End With
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include, once the button from form 1 has been clicked, the textboxes that is in form1 will be added to the listview in form2. Is that possible? There are no buttons to add row/data in form2, it's just a listview.

Comment: I tried your given code, it's still having the same problem or based on LarsTech, it keeps on making a new listview table and it's not actually adding a row.